# Need help understanding robust optimization formulation

Tags: modeling, robust-optimization

I am reading these [notes](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/robust_notes.pdf) from Stanford called "Optimization with uncertain data".

In section 2.2, Example 2 (page 7), the author mentions the following portfolio problem $(P)$:

$$
\max \; t
$$
subject to
\begin{align*}
\text{Prob}\left(\sum_i R_i x_i \ge t\right) &\ge 1-\epsilon \\
\sum_i x_i &= 1 \\
x_i &\ge 0 \quad \forall i
\end{align*}
where $R_i$ (the random return of each asset $i$) and $\epsilon$ (the value at risk) are given parameters.

Assuming $R_i \in [\mu_i -\text{u}_i,\mu_i +\text{u}_i]$ with $\text{E}(R_i)=\mu_i$, the author shows that the problem is equivalent to maximizing
$$
\sum_i \mu_i x_i -\sqrt{2 \log \frac{1}{\epsilon}} \lVert\text{diag}(\text{u})x \rVert_2 
$$
subject to
\begin{align*}
\sum_i x_i &= 1 \\
x_i &\ge 0 \quad \forall i
\end{align*}

And states:

> This corresponds to the uncertainty set given by the scaled $\ell_2$
> ball
>
> $$ \mathcal{U}=\{u \in \mathbb{R}^n , \lVert\text{diag}(u)^{-1/2}u \rVert_2 \le \sqrt{2 \log \frac{1}{\epsilon}}\} $$
> in the robust inequality $\sum_i (\mu_i+u_i)x_i \le t$ for all $u\in \mathcal{U}$.

---

I don't understand the last quoted part ($\text{diag}(u)^{-1/2}u$?) and suspect there is at least one typo ($\sum_i (\mu_i+u_i)x_i \color{red}{\ge} t$?). In the end, if I want to solve the initial problem, what formulation do I use ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a typo in the document, and perhaps some confusion between parameters $\text{u}$ and variables $u$.

My understanding is that the initial problem $(P)$ is equivalent to:

$$
\max_x \; \sum_i \mu_i x_i -\sqrt{2 \log \frac{1}{\epsilon}} \lVert\text{diag}(\text{u})x \rVert_2 
$$
subject to
\begin{align*}
\sum_i x_i &= 1 \\
x_i &\ge 0 \quad \forall i
\end{align*}

and to:
$$
\max_{x,t,u} \; t
$$
subject to
\begin{align*}
\sum_i x_i &= 1 \\
x_i &\ge 0 \quad \forall i \\
\sum_i (\mu_i + u_i\text{u}_i)x_i &\ge t \\
\lVert u  \rVert_2 &\le \sqrt{2 \log \frac{1}{\epsilon}}
\end{align*}